# How do you market assets that are niche but that those people definitely want?

Tags: marketing

I just got done canvasing/surveying developers, and it is clear that there is a market for a few niche categories of audio assets that I suspected would be useful to them. While the overall category of assets is commonly desired, it can only be broken down into separate categories, which individually are completely niche due to the wide variety of games nowadays.

How can a niche but useful asset be effectively marketed to (mostly indie) game developers? It is known that there are people out there who want it, but the likelihood of a completely random individual wanting it is low. So if the asset was created, and there was low competition among asset producers for it, how could one ensure at least some of those people find it (without actually cold-calling them)?
I would explain in more detail, but I don't want to come off as though I'm trying to advertise anything here.

Comment: If it's audio you could just put it up on all the engine stores and ensure that the version for each engine is nicely packaged. Then make sure there is a good overview of the kinds of sounds available. I know that Unity and Unreal both have quite good asset stores that are used frequently and I'd be surprised if there isn't anything out there for RPG-maker and some of the more niche engines